# Multiple active keys on an account?

Tags: active-key

Is it possible to have multiple active keys in an account? Say I wanted to have one at home and another where I want to share with a person I trust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible ([example](https://bloks.io/account/eosio.prods)). Any permission (owner/active/or otherwise) can have many keys associated with them (not sure the max limit).

You will want to include the new key with a weight of 1 (same as your original key), and leave your active permission's threshold at 1.

You can do this here, but be very,very,very careful:
https://toolkit.genereos.io/account/advanced

Comment: Which wallets lets you do this? And how can one do this in cleos?

Comment: If you'd like a GUI you can use Scatter and the link I posted above. If you'd like to use cleos, you'll need to execute `cleos push action` and call the `updateAuth` method on the `eosio` smart contract. If you are not too confident with cleos, I'd recommend using scatter and the link above, it can be very easy to mistype the cleos command and make your account unrecoverable.